# Dynamically modifying lazy loaded routes not working

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I am trying to modify routes in a lazy-loaded feature module but no success. I tried several approaches including `router.reset(newRoutes)` but none seem to work. (Angular 9)

```
export class FeatureModule {
  static forRoot(routes?: Routes) {
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      providers: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes).providers // option 1
        // provideRoutes(routes), // option 2
        // { provide: ROUTES, useValue: routes }, // option 3
      ]
    }.ngModule
  }
}
```

`FeatureModule` is lazy loaded into the main app:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./feature/feature.module').then((m) => m.FeatureModule.forRoot(customRoutes)
```

None of the options work. Angular does not detect those dynamically provided routes

If I provide static default routes in the `imports` then it works but then I am not able to modify the routes

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(defaultRoutes)]
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

I wonder if this has something to do with Angular itself or I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 4):

That will not work, because `imports` and `providers` are two different things and the RouterModule is a Module so it should be placed in the `imports` section.

Using dynamic routes in a lazy-module it's a little tricky, i dont know if there is another way, but you could try the following:

Use and export a variable in the `FeatureModule` and fill the routes on the lazy-load.

```
export const FeatureModuleRoutes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(FeatureModuleRoutes)]
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

Lets create an InjectionToken and store the routes in there.

```
//Create the injection token
const ROUTES_STORE = new InjectionToken("Loading lazy routes");

//In your AppModule provide the routes that you need.
   {
      provide: ROUTES_STORE,
      useValue: [{featureRoutes: [{path: "", component: FeatureComponent}]}]
    },
```

To inject the token you need an injector, the AppModule it is called before the lazy-load, so you could provide an static injector and use it later.

```
export class AppModule {
  static mInjector: Injector;

  //Inject the Injector so we can access it before de Lazy Module
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    AppModule.mInjector = injector;
  }
}
```

Now you have an injector and the routes, it is time to fill your FeatureModuleRoutes. The `m` it is the file so you can access to your variable before is loaded.

```
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./feature/feature.module").then(m => {
        const routeStore = AppModule.mInjector.get(ROUTES_STORE);
        routeStore.featureRoutes
          .forEach(route => (m.FeatureModuleRoutes as Array<any>).push(route));
        return m.FeatureModule;
      })
```

And that is it, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this - even though I didn't need the injector in my case, the extra hook in the loadChildren callback did exactly what I needed, and I was able to contribute additional routes at the point of lazy loading.

Comment: It seems like in the last code block, the `ROUTES_STORE` injection token has to be known as a constant. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to support a dynamic number of routes in feature module that are unknown at the time of writing. Am I missing something obvious or would that be an entirely separate problem to start with?

Comment: The export of FeatureModuleRoutes is key to how this works. The routeStore is not required to get the list of routes working. Consider in the import to call out to DB and get the router list, then load routes. First change DB strings to actual component definitions.